# What is the best way to raise handle bars

Tags: frames, handlebars

I have bought a second hand 19 inch frame and I am normally used to a 20.5 inch.

The bike rides OK but I would benefit from raising the handlebars.

I have read about fork steerer tube extenders and adjustable bicycle stems.

I personally think the fork extender would be a better way, are there any advantages or disadvantages to either?

Comment: What type of bike is it? (E.g. road bike, mountain bike, city bike) Does your bike have a _threaded_ or _threadless_ headset? The difference is explained in the following answer:   https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/10078/30402

Comment: hybrid, threaded

Answer (score 3):

A stem with a greater angle and rise, potentially coupled with a riser handlebar will be a stronger solution than a steerer extender. If you are doing casual riding on flat ground a steerer extender is probably OK. If you are riding rough terrain and putting a lot of force through the bars an extender may not be able to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have a threaded steerer? Like this?

[image]

If so, then there are a few options:

If you just want a quick bike fit fix and be done with it, then, as you most likely have a quill stem, get one with higher height and/or angle:

[image]

But, if you want a long-term thing and 'get with the times', you can fit a quill stem to threadless adapter:

(2nd image is an expander stem version, but it also works the same)

[image]
[image]

Though you will also need to buy an actual threadless stem too.

Comment: The "wedge" (first three) stem is generally seen as a more robust and safer design than the "slit and cone" (last example).